# CheckListBox widget size (height) fitted to items in it in wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, checklistbox

I have CheckListBox widget in my app.
During its life-cycle I am removing or adding new items to it.
I would like to change its size (especially height) in an "automated" way.
I would like to change its height to display all items and not showing the scroll bar.
Is it possible?

Another issue is that when I am creating such widget with 2 items I got to much height (height is about for 4 items, so 2 lines are empty).
I do not want to see such "ugly" layout.
My widget size does not fit automatically to items in it.

I am using sizers in my app and I am trying to use Layout() method but it does not help.
How to resolve this problem without changing the size in manually way bu using "size=()" parameter?

Here's an example of my app.
[image]

I am listing Com ports in my app.
I my example before I have listed 2 com ports, but after disconnecting one of them and after pressing [refresh] button my app discovered only 1 com port. It is okay.
But I would like to fit the height of checklistbox to only this one com.
How to do that?

I would like to have "automated" look like below:
[image: image2]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create a very small example which demonstrates your problem? It is hard to understand what exactly you have on mind.

Comment: Please see the image from zetcode portal: http://zetcode.com/img/gui/wxpython/repository.png  I would have to have widget fit to last item in it, so in this cases the widget height should ends after "ash" string. Why it is so big? How to fit it automatically?

Comment: I came here after Googling the same question. Your example looks like the checklistbox is set to fill the parent area completely. Mine OTOH is a rectangle within the parent area but only sizes itself on creation.